# importing modules in multiple python scripts files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below script files:

```
 1. master.py
 2. setup.py
 4. core1.py
 5. core2.py
```

master.py:

```
 import setup.py
 import  standard.py
 import  core1.py
 import core2.py

 if __name__ = '__main__':
     #how to access var1, var2, var3..var100 of setup1?
     do something
```

setup.py:

```
 def somefunction():
      var1 = x
      var2 = y
      var3 = z
      #.... so on var100 = z100
```

core1.py:

```
    import setup
    #how to access var1, var2, var3..var100 of setup1?
     #written few  functions which require setup.py variables output
```

core2.py:

```
    import setup
    #how to acess var1, var2, var3..var100 of setup1?
    #written few  functions which require setup.py variables output
```

Program execution flow:

```
 -->run master.py--> import setup, core1, core2, --> call core1 functions inside master.py ---> call core2 functions inside master.py
```

1. how to access var1, var2, var3..var100 of setup1 script variables in all the script?
2. Please correct me if anything mistakes i am doing in execution flow design.

Comment: Use a dict not 100 different variables.

Comment: Noted, I will use dict

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `var1 ... var100` variables `global`, so that they can be accessed outside of the function they're in.

To access them in each file, you need to first call the function in `setup.py` (like `setup.someFunction()`), and then you can use them as you would use variables normally.

EDIT: In answer to your comment, yes, you want to call it in all of the files.

Comment: perfect,  so i want to call this setup.someFunction()) in all scripts like master.py,core1 and 2?